# Fallout 3 V.A.T.S. glitch on Xbox 360

Tags: fallout-3

So, I was just about to finish killing some radroaches, when V.A.T.S. stopped working. I kept pressing RT but nothing happened, so i had to individually kill all of the radroaches without V.A.T.S. This should probably be fixed soon. If anyone could help me it would be nice.

Comment: Not really sure what sort of answer you're looking for here. What exactly are you hoping we can help you with?

Comment: I'm kinda hoping that someone can maybe help me fix it. But it seems that has been done.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your character ran out if Action Points (AP) they're a resource determined by your agility, perks, clothing, and consumables. They are represented by the bar on the bottom right corner of your screen.

AP is consumed by using VATS and will regenerate on its own. When you are out of AP you can enter VATS mode but will be unable to attack enemies. If this happens you will have to fight enemies normally until your AP has regenerated enough to use VATS again.

If you are unable to enter VATS at all (and this does not sound like the issue) then you may have encountered one of the many glitches on Fallout 3. Restart your console or update your game if possible.

Answer (score -1):

That has also happened to me. I suggest saving then killing your self with a fragmentation mine or grenade, it should fix it after that.

Comment: What do I do if I have no grenades or mines?